# What metrics should I look at to find why the Tools->Options dialog is slow in the delphi xe5 IDE?

Tags: windows-7, performance, delphi

I am have Delphi XE5 installed on two laptops at work, one is newer with an SSD, 16GB, fast processor, and one older with 8GB. Both laptops run Windows 7 64 bit SP1 with the latest changes.

The problem that I am having is that Delphi XE5 is slower on the newer laptop than it is on the old one. On the new computer opening the Tools->Options dialog takes 4-5seconds while on the old one it takes 1-2seconds. I checked all the dll versions and dependencies and the versions are the same on both laptops.

Both laptops run the System Center Endpoint Protection. One difference is that the new laptop runs Bitlocker and the C partition is encrypted.

Now, I am trying to figure out why opening the options dialog on the new one is much slower. I spent some time reading suggestions here and I tried a few things, but I hit a wall.

One thing I tried was to run process monitor and see exactly the activity that happens in the IDE when I opened the dialog. I could notice a gap of 2s of inactivity while the options dialog was opened on the new laptop.

Another thing I tried was to run the windows performance toolkit. I recorded the activity when I opened the options dialog. There is a lot of information that is available but I don't know exactly what I should look at. Nothing seems to be out of the ordinary.

One other thing that happens is that even the application I compile and run in Delphi is slower on the new laptop. That's another problem. When I run it debug mode on the new laptop, most of the time is spent pre-creating the form objects in memory. Somehow this process is a lot faster on the old laptop.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The laptop with an SSD, I assume the SSD, is the only drive

Comment: Actually the new computer has two drives. One is SSD (C) the other one is not. Both are encrypted. The system is on the SSD drive. The model is SAMSUNG SSD SM841N mSATA SCSI Disk Device. Interesting enough I looked in the bios and the SSD is not AHCI, it is RAID something... I cannot touch the bios settings due to policy.

Comment: RAID could explain the problem.  You will have to change it, in order to determine, if that is the reason.  *"RAID something"*, please be specific, if you want help.

Comment: For sure. I was in the middle of something and I had to reboot the laptop to see again the setting. The laptop is a Dell Precision M4700. The setting in the BIOS for SATA Operation is RAID On = SATA is configured to support RAID model (Intel Rapid Restore Technology). The other options are: Disabled, ATA and AHCI.

Comment: @Ramhound: I also want to add, that I run the AS SSD benchmark and the results looked OK. I can post them if you want.

Comment: I checked with a colleague of mine who has an identical laptop. The SATA setting is the same as mine and he doesn't have this problem with Delphi.

Comment: So are you using a RAID or not?  I can't tell since you have not clarified your question.

Comment: @Ramhound; Yes, and I cannot change it for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out what the problem is! The AC adapter that I currently have doesn't provide enough power. Its output is 6.7A. The laptop, Dell Precision M4700 requires at least 9.23A. I also use it with a docking station. I never thought of checking the adapter until I found today the last post here: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19484538 and it gave me the idea to do it.